# How to find a max value for any quantity of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need to find Max values for any number of arrays within the function. For example, user can add 1 array or 10 arrays. Output should show max values for each of the arrays.

Currently, my code works only if 1 array is provided.
Please let me know what is wrong.

```
function getMaxs(args){
array = args;
var max = array[0];

for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(max < array[i]){
        max = array[i];
    }
}
console.log(max);
return max;

}

getMaxs([5, 6, 7], [18, 19, 20], [5, 7, 3, 10]); // output is 7
getMaxs([5, 6, 7]); // output is 7
getMaxs([18, 19, 20], [5, 10, 74, 394]); // output is 20
```

Comment: your `args` receives an array of arrays, [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) this array before check for the max

Comment: You only check the first array, any of the rest are not actually passed to the function as the `args` parameter.

Comment: `function getMaxs(...args){ return Math.max(...args.flat()) }`

Comment: _“Input should show max values for each of the arrays”_ - so you want the maximum value of _each_ sub-array, not just _one_ overall maximum across all of them? Well then using a skalar `max` variable doesn’t make much sense to begin with, you would need to return an _array_ then.

Comment: Or for each array, that returns an array ->  `function getMaxs(...args){ return args.map(m => Math.max(...m)) }`

Answer (score 2):

If you need a max for every provided array:

```js
const getMaxs = (...args) => args.map(arr => Math.max(...arr));

console.log( getMaxs([5, 6, 7], [18, 19, 20], [5, 7, 3, 10]) ); // [7, 20, 10]
console.log( getMaxs([5, 6, 7]) );                              // [7]
console.log( getMaxs([18, 19, 20], [5, 10, 74, 394]) );         // [20, 394]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care which sub-array the result comes from, you can use [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
function getMaxs(array) {
    const flatArray = array.flat();
    return Math.max(...flatArray);
}

const arr = [[5, 6, 7], [18, 19, 20], [5, 7, 3, 10]];
const max = getMaxs(arr);

console.log(max);
```

Comment: I think they want the maximum per sub-array, not the overall maximum.

Comment: Based on the original code, it looks like they want the overall max. I'll let the OP update their question if this isn't what they're looking for and update my answer as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Something along these lines:

```js
function getMaxs(...arrays) {
    return Math.max(...arrays.flat());
}

// usage
getMaxs([5, 6, 7], [18, 19, 20], [5, 7, 3, 10]); // output is 20
getMaxs([5, 6, 7]); // output is 7
getMaxs([18, 19, 20], [5, 10, 74, 394]); // output is 394
```

Related: [The arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) in case you can't use rest parameters. In that case, you probably don't support `flat` either, which in that case I'll recommend you to look for a polyfill somewhere.

Comment: You juste made me discover that there are two ways of qualifying the splat operator (`...`) in JavaScript depending on the context (Rest parameter VS Spread syntax). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .flat() function, so the arrays would merge and become one, like this:

```
function getMaxs(args){
  array = args.flat();
  //it will now see it as one big array
  ....
}
```

But, the .flat() function may not work on older browsers, so you may also do this:

```
array = args.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
```

The effect will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Iraklis solution is fine, but it suppose you give an array of arrays. However, if you want to pass arrays as separated arguments, you could use the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```js
function getMaxs(...arrays) {
  const max = Math.max(...arrays.flat())
  console.log(max) // DEBUG
  return max
}
getMaxs([5, 6, 7], [18, 19, 20], [5, 7, 3, 10])
getMaxs([5, 6, 7])
getMaxs([18, 19, 20], [5, 10, 74, 394])
```

Of course, you should be careful about browser compatibility:

[image]

Comment: `Of course, you should be careful about browser compatibility:`   That is something I never do these days, constantly chasing your tail and having to check if your code is compatible with X & Y browser is the fastest way to go insane.. :),.   If your not currently doing this, try looking into polyfilling & transpiling.  Your sanity / sex life, everything will improve..

Comment: @Keith — It really depends of OP's stack... I'm just warning anyway. But as you do, I'd suggest using something like babel to avoid having to care about it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getMaxs(...args) {
  array = args.flat();
  var max = array[0];

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (max < array[i]) {
      max = array[i];
    }
  }
  // console.log(max);
  return max;
}

console.log(getMaxs([5, 6, 7], [18, 19, 20], [5, 7, 3, 10]));
console.log(getMaxs([5, 6, 7]));
console.log(getMaxs([18, 19, 20], [5, 10, 74, 394]));
```

the above one will be the solution for your question. You can check the below screenshots for your reference.

For this input i have added screen shots for your reference how it will process the code
    getMaxs([5, 6, 7], [18, 19, 20], [5, 7, 3, 10])

now it will take the whole

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me. This version of code returns only the last array.

Comment: My bad sorry if the 2 nd line code is updated with 
array = args.flat();
. it will work fine